# Include MATLAB code listing compiled into HTML with correct colors

Tags: listings, tex4ht, html, matlab, matlab-prettifier

I am compiling a LaTeX file `my_document.tex` into an HTML page `my_document.html` using htlatex with the following command:

```
htlatex my_document.tex "xhtml,mathml-" " -cmozhtf"
```

I have a MATLAB code file `main.m` that I want to include in `my_document.html` with formatting that matches the MATLAB editor. When compiling with `pdflatex`, I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstset{
    style=Matlab-editor
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{main.m}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above code with `htlatex`, however, creates output that is black-and-white. Our current approach is to use [m2tex](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5010-m2tex) to translate the .m file into a .tex file, but this makes the process of updating the HTML files more complicated because it adds a step, so I'm trying to find a way to simplify the process. I've included one approach as an answer, below, but am looking for other suggestions.

**EDIT:** Here is an example MATLAB file, `main.m`:

```
% This is a comment
var = "this is a string";

for i = 1:5
    doThing(i)
end

disp this_is_some_text

function doThing(i)
    fprintf('Number %d\n', i)
end
```

In the MATLAB code editor, `main.m` looks like the following screenshot, so the goal is to make the HTML output match this as well:

[image: the appearance of main.m in the MATLAB code editor]

Comment: Can you please add also the `matlab` code to your question? I cannot test it without that.

Comment: The particular choice of MATLAB code is not important, but I added an example that includes most of the important components of MATLAB code (comments, keywords, strings, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with colors is a bit complicated with TeX4ht. Stuff like `\textcolor` works, but colors that are set by `\color` cannot be supported out of the box. You need to add some HTML tags with color information yourself.

For listings, we can use hooks provided by the package to insert some elements around each keyword. We can get the current color and insert CSS instructions.

Try this configuration file, `config.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter

\lst@AddToHook{OutputBox}{%
% get current color in the CSS form
\extractcolorspec{.}\html@color%
\expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@color{HTML}\html@color%
\HCode{<span style="color:\#\html@color">}}% init

\lst@AddToHook{PostOutput}{\HCode{</span>}}%
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

In the `OutputBox` hook, we define the `\html@color` macro. It holds the current color suitable for CSS thanks to `\extractcolorspec` and `\convertcolorspec` commands. We insert it to the HTML output thanks to     `\lst@AddToHook{PostOutput}{\HCode{</span>}}` command. In the `PostOutput` hook, we insert the closing `</span>` tag.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}


\lstset{
    style=Matlab-editor
}


\begin{document}

Listings environment:

\begin{lstlisting}
function y = f(x)
    % comment
    y = x^2
    disp('1hll')
    [t, x] = ode45(@f, [0, 1], 0)
end
\end{lstlisting}

Included mathlab:

    \lstinputlisting{main.m}
\end{document}
```

Compile using (don't use `htlatex`, it is deprecated):

```
make4ht -c config.cfg -m draft my_document.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

One last thing. I've found a bug in the configuration file for the Color package, `color.4ht`. It prevents the correct conversion of colors. Here is the correct version:

```
% color.4ht (2022-02-01-17:18), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-02-01-17:18}

\expandafter\ifx \csname color:def\endcsname\relax
    \let\color:def\def
\else  \expandafter\endinput\fi
\let\:temp\begingroup
\HLet\color@setgroup\:temp
\def\HColor{\:warning{\string\Hcode{...}{...} is deprecated; Use
   \string\Configure{HColor}{...}{...}}\Configure{HColor}}
\NewConfigure{HColor}[2]{\if !#1!\if!#2!\let\HColor\relax \else \edef\HColor{#2}\fi
\else
   \expandafter\edef\csname CLR:#1\endcsname{#2}\fi}
\def\:temp#1#2#3{%
  \@ifundefined{color@#2}%
    {\c@lor@error{model `#2'}}%
    {\@ifundefined{\string\color @#1}{}%
      {\PackageInfo{color}{Redefining color #1}}%
     \csname color@#2\expandafter\endcsname
         \csname\string\color @#1\endcsname{#3}}}
\ifx \definecolor\:temp
   \pend:defIII\definecolor{%
     \expandafter\ifx\csname HColor:##2\endcsname\relax\else
        \csname HColor:##2\endcsname ##3 //%
        \edef\:temp{{HColor}{##1}{\HColor}}%
        \expandafter\Configure\:temp
     \fi}
\fi

\NewConfigure{color}{1}
\def\:tempc#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\protect\a:textcolor
      \color#1{#2}#3\protect\b:textcolor}}
\HLet\@textcolor=\:tempc
\NewConfigure{textcolor}{2}
   \def\pagecolor{%
  \begingroup \a:pagecolor
      \let\ignorespaces\endgroup
      \let\set@color\set@page@color
      \color}
\NewConfigure{pagecolor}{1}
\def\:tempa[#1]#2{\a:color{#1 #2}\o:@undeclaredcolor:[#1]{#2}}
\HLet\@undeclaredcolor\:tempa
\pend:defI\@declaredcolor{\a:color{##1}}
\NewConfigure{SetHColor}[2]{{%
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\:temp \csname CLR:#2\endcsname
   \ifx \:temp\relax
      \edef\:temp{#2 //}\expandafter\get:HColor\:temp
      \ifx \HColor\relax
          \expandafter\ifx \csname get!HColor\endcsname\relax \else
  \edef\:temp{#2!//}\expandafter\csname get!HColor\expandafter\endcsname\:temp
\fi
%
      \fi
   \else             \let\HColor=\:temp \fi
   \ifx \HColor\relax
      \:warning{missing \string\Configure{HColor}{#2}{...}
           (in LaTeX: \csname\string\color @#2\endcsname)}%
      \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname CLR:#2\endcsname\empty
    \else #1\fi }}
\def\get:HColor#1 #2//{%
  \if\relax#2\relax
  % \expandafter\ifx \csname HColor:#1\endcsname\relax
     \let\HColor=\relax
     \expandafter\ifx \csname\string\color @#1\endcsname \relax\else
   \expandafter\ifx \csname colortyp:\endcsname\relax \else
      \csname colortyp:\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
         \csname\string\color @#1\expandafter\endcsname
         \space . //%
\fi \fi
%
  \else
     \csname HColor:#1\endcsname #2 //%
  \fi
}
\def\c:HColor:gray:{\def\HColor:gray##1 ##2//}
\Configure{HColor:gray}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\def\c:HColor:rgb:{\def\HColor:rgb##1,##2,##3 ##4//}
\Configure{HColor:rgb}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\def\c:HColor:cmyk:{\def\HColor:cmyk##1,##2,##3,##4 ##5//}
\Configure{HColor:cmyk}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}

\long\def\:temp#1#2#3{%
   \ifcolors@
      \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{\relax}\ifx\:temp\:tempa
      \a:colorbox \else \a:fcolorbox \fi
   \fi
   {#1{\leavevmode #2{\set@color#3}}}%
   \ifcolors@
      \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{\relax}\ifx\:temp\:tempa
      \b:colorbox \else \b:fcolorbox \fi
   \fi
}
\HLet\color@b@x\:temp
\NewConfigure{colorbox}{2}
\NewConfigure{fcolorbox}{2}

\Hinput{color}
\endinput
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! How and where do I include the corrected version of `color.4ht`?

Comment: Never mind, I found it. It is located in `C:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\generic\tex4ht` on my system.

Comment: Have you submitted a bug report or pull request for the change to `color.4ht` so that the distributed version will have the fix?

Comment: There's one minor flaw in the HTML output. The text `this_is_some_text` should be purple since it is a string. Personally, I'm fine with it as-is because I tend to rewrite lines like `disp this_is_some_text` as `disp('this_is_some_text')`.

Comment: Similarly, the second line of "Included mathlab" should have purple text for "this is a string".

Comment: @PaulWintz I've updated TeX4ht sources, so it should be available in TeX Live soon (it is not here yet).

Comment: @PaulWintz the colors are the same for me as in PDF, maybe Listings need some additional configuration to make extra strings in color?

Answer (score 0):

When the following .tex file is compiled with `htlatex`, the code in the `lstlisting` environment is formatted pretty well, but the code that is imported with `lstinputlisting` is still black and white.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier} % Pretty print Matlab code

% Set the styles for different categories of code to arbitrary and distinct styles.
\lstset{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,            % Appears as class=ectt-1000 in HTML
    keywordstyle=\rmfamily\bfseries, % Appears as class=ecbx-1000 in HTML
    commentstyle=\sffamily,          % Appears as class=ecss-1000 in HTML
    stringstyle=\sffamily\slshape    % Appears as class=ecsi-1000 and tcsi-1000 in HTML
}

\begin{document}

% Set the font-family and color in the CSS based on the class associated with 
% each span of text. The values "ectt-1000", etc., were found by inspecting 
% the compiled HTML page in Google Chrome. 
% Note: The \Css command only works when compiling with htlatex.
\Css{div.lstlisting .ectt-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:black}}   % Basic
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecss-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:green}}   % Comments
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecbx-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:blue}}    % Keywords
\Css{div.lstlisting .tcsi-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:purple}}  % String (delimiter)
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecsi-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:purple}}  % String (interior)

% Code in the lstlisting environment is rendered reasonable well.
\begin{lstlisting}
function y = f(x)
    % comment 
    y = x^2 
    disp('1hll')
    [t, x] = ode45(@f, [0, 1], 0)
end
\end{lstlisting}

% Code from lstinputlisting is still black and white.
\lstinputlisting{Matlab2tex_1_2/f.m}

\end{document}
```

This approach feels very hack-y and I don't understand the `\Css` commands very well.